# CSS footer - body bug

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <style>
        html, body, #container {
            height:100%;
        }

        #container {
            height:auto;
            min-height:100%;
            position:relative;
        }
    </style>
        <body>
            <div id="container" style="background-color:#0000FF;">body</div>
            <div style="background-color:#FF0000;height:100px;">footer</div>
        </body>
</html>
```

JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hnz1ys27/

How to hide the scrollbar and make the footer stick to the bottom of the page? In my code the footer goes BELLOW the bottom of the page and the user must scroll, despite the only 1 line of body.

Comment: You mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0f0prkcy/?

Comment: @j08691: Thanks, seems right! Please give me a moment to test it.

Comment: you can do like http://jsfiddle.net/hnz1ys27/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page needs a `<head></head>` where you should insert your css code.
And here is the right way of using JFriddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hnz1ys27/3/

To make the footer stick to the bottom you can use the position:absolute; and the bottom:0px;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <!-- Your page do not have a head -->
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                padding: 0px;
                background-color:blue;
            }
            #container{
               background-color:green;
            }
            #footer {
               position:absolute;
               left:0px;
               bottom:0px;
               width: 100%;
               background-color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">This is my body</div>
        <div id="footer">This is my footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Edit :
Footer on the bottom of container : http://jsfiddle.net/hnz1ys27/5/

Comment: Yeah that is happening when your div is min-height:100%.
(Εχεις 2 κουτια και το πρώτο του έχεις βαλει ελάχιστο υψος όσο το μέγεθος της οθόνης)

Comment: The code works, but there is a bug if you set the height in the container to e.g. 1000px and then scroll down. In that case the footer doesn't stay on the bottom.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hnz1ys27/5/ this are not bugs. This is css, it do what you write :P